# MySQL Stored procedure remembers outdated temporary table schema, leading to unknown column error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

In the following MySQL code, the first two blocks drop and create a temporary table **_temp** (with different column labels) and **select *** from it without a problem.  Then, I create a stored procedure that does the same thing (i.e., **select * from _temp**), and it works first time, but not the second, failing with

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'test._temp.f' in 'field list'

It seems like **select * from _temp** on its own correctly handles the change in table columns, but the previous columns names are remembered across stored procedure calls.  Am I doing something wrong, or is there a workaround?

### MySQL Code

```
drop temporary table if exists _temp;
create temporary table _temp select 'first' as f;
select * from _temp;

drop temporary table if exists _temp;
create temporary table _temp select 'second' as s;
select * from _temp;

drop procedure if exists selectTemp;
create procedure selectTemp()
select * from _temp;

drop temporary table if exists _temp;
create temporary table _temp select 'first' as f;
call selectTemp();

drop temporary table if exists _temp;
create temporary table _temp select 'second' as s;
call selectTemp();
```

### Transcript

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

```
mysql> source temp.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

+-------+
| f     |
+-------+
| first |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

+--------+
| s      |
+--------+
| second |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

+-------+
| f     |
+-------+
| first |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'test._temp.f' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After paring this down to a minimal working example, and distilling the essential elements, searching for a bug report, this became much easier.  It turns out that this was reported all the way back in 2005 as:

- [Bug #12257   SELECT * inside PROCEDURE gives "Unknown column" on second loop if tbl changed](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12257)

Some of the bugs marked as a duplicate of that are actually more along the lines of the example:

- [Bug #15766   select * from table inside stored procedure uses old field names](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15766)
- [Bug #49333   Unknown column 'test.TEMPTABLE.column1' in 'field list'](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49333)
- [Bug #62406   new cursor, on table with same name but different structure as used before fails](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62406)

The bug is closed, but apparently not fixed yet, though 5.6 mentions the behavior. From the comments in the bug report:

> Noted in 5.6.6 changelog.
>
> "Unknown column" errors or bad data could result from changing the set
>   of columns in a table used within a stored program between  executions
>   of the program or while the table was used within a program loop.